# Creating a automation email in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow

I'm trying to create a way in flow to automate sending the same 5 templates of emails again and again as long as a specific field inside a record is between 50% to 100%.

I want to send it every day and sometimes every week until the record field gets to a certain %.

I know how to set up a flow that will start and stop depending on the field value but I don't know how to loop the emails and not only schedule them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can create scheduled flow which query record by your specific field value and then loop these records to send emails.